# jQuery UI Datepicker default year always 2013

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker that is supposed to go from 1803 to 1995, but if you pick a day and month without choosing the year, it defaults to 2013, even though it would display 1803. How could I fix this?

Here is my code

```
$(function() {
        $( "#date" ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: "1803:1995",
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",

        });
    });
```

I have tried using default date, but then that stops me from changing the year.

Comment: can u make a fiddle .

Comment: *"I have tried using default date, but then that stops me from changing the year."* Er, no.

Comment: *"if you pick a day and month without choosing the year, it defaults to 2013, even though it would display 1803"* I can replicate that: http://jsbin.com/UsePaPE/1/edit Recommend reporting it as a bug.

Comment: Well, that's weird, it works now.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, by default it is using the **current date**.  To change this use either  options [**`defaultDate`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) or **`setDate`**

```
$(function() {
        $( "#date" ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: "1803:1995",
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          defaultDate: '1803-01-01'

        });
    });
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QDGeb/1/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the defaultDate  property, your code becomes like this

```
$(function() {
        $( "#date" ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: "1803:1995",
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          defaultDate: "1803-01-01"

        });
    });
```

Comment: Yeah ok, for some stupid reason, the first time I tried that it didn't work -_-